# Suspend a Moodle user by using Web service API functions

Tags: php, curl, moodle

I am trying to suspend a user in Moodle by using  Moodle's  [Web service API functions](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions) in PHP.
I can change user fields like firstname, but I am not capable to suspend the user.

It always returns "null".

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$serverurl = "http://localhost/web/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&wsfunction=core_user_update_users&moodlewsrestformat=json";
$params = "users[0][id]=4&users[0][preferences][0][type]=suspended&users[0][preferences][0][value]=true";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $serverurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($response);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspending a user was added to the Web Services in [MDL-31465](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-31465) which made it into version 3.2. If you're on an older version and don't want to upgrade, you can use the `core_user_update_users` function and set `auth` to `nologin`.

The API returning `null` does not indicate an error - if something goes wrong, you'll get a more verbose error.

Answer (score 1):

with moodle 3.7 should work, but not using"preferences" as in above example but
using following template:

wsfunction=core_user_update_users&users[0][id]=1234&users[0][suspended]=1